# uv image editor not sho

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

[image]

As you can see in the picture everytime I try to unwrap, blender says to put a modifier that is not there first. no object In any other collection is selected nor do they have said modifier.
I also deleted my UV's and created new ones.

Comment: maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: It's fixed! I don't know why, I didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try unchecking the **Use Subsurf Modifier** in the Unwrap popup.

[image]